# postfix - warning: connect to transport private/smtp: Connection refused

Tags: email, smtp, postfix

I have been having trouble with my postfix+dovecot mailserver. Every time I try to send an email to a different server (gmail etc.) I get the following messages in the log:

```
postfix/qmgr[28918]: warning: connect to transport private/smtp: Connection refused
postfix/error[29298]: BB36617ABFB: to=<email@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=575, delays=575/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)
```

Somehow, postfix cannot connect to it's postscreen transport. This is my main.cf (with domains replaced):

```
## These are all default Postfix settings that we won't change
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
inet_protocols = ipv4, ipv6
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -c /etc/dovecot/conf.d/99-mail-stack-delivery.conf -m "${EXTENSION}"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/dovecot-auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom

## Settings below this line are things we're modifying or adding

## Your mail server identity options
myhostname = domain1.com
mydestination = mail.domain1.com, localhost, mx.domain1.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 10.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 172.17.0.0/16

## Customized smtpd paramters
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_unknown_helo_hostname, permit
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, reject_invalid_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_sender
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_sender_login_mismatch
smtpd_sender_login_maps = $virtual_mailbox_maps

## Dealing with rejection: use permanent 550 errors to stop retries
unknown_address_reject_code = 550
unknown_hostname_reject_code = 550
unknown_client_reject_code = 550

## customized TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_ask_ccert = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = somewhere.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = somewhere.key
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtpd_tls_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s

## Customized Dovecot and virtual user-specific settings
canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/canonical
home_mailbox = Maildir/
message_size_limit = 104857600
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_alias_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual-mailbox-domains
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual-mailbox-users
virtual_transport = dovecot

## This setting will generate an error if you restart Postfix before
## adding the appropriate service definition in master.cf, so make
## sure to get that taken care of!
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1

## Customized milter settings
milter_default_action = accept
milter_connect_macros = j {daemon_name} v {if_name} _
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
smtpd_milters = unix:/var/spool/postfix/spamass/spamass.sock unix:/var/spool/postfix/opendkim/opendkim.sock

## Other customized mail server settings
default_destination_concurrency_limit = 5
disable_vrfy_command = yes
relay_destination_concurrency_limit = 1
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may

postscreen_greet_action = enforce
postscreen_dnsbl_action = enforce
postscreen_access_list = permit_mynetworks
postscreen_dnsbl_sites = zen.spamhaus.org, b.barracudacentral.org, bl.spamcop.net
myorigin = $myhostname
```

And my master.cf:

```
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       1       postscreen
smtpd     pass  -       -       n       -       -       smtpd
dnsblog   unix  -       -       n       -       0       dnsblog
tlsproxy  unix  -       -       n       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
pickup    unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache

maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/local/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}

dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=mail:mail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver
  -f ${sender} -d ${user}@${nexthop} -a ${recipient}
```

virtual-mailbox-domains:

```
domain1.com OK
domain2.net OK
```

My server is also running IPv6, not sure if that has to do with anything though. If you need any more info just drop a comment ;)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, the line

```
smtp unix - - n - - smtp
```

which I commented out because I got duplicate warnings from postmap is required. I just put it back in there and it started working.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.

- postmap is giving a warning : **postmap: warning: master.cf.db: duplicate entry: "smtp"**
- unable to send mails to external email addresses

I had commented the line **smtp unix - - n - - smtp** because of that.

Removing the comment solved the problem.

Comment: There's already an answer from **8 years ago** saying the same.

Comment: @ChanganAuto : do you have a link to that same answer please?

Comment: @ArnoLambert welcome to superuser. The accepted answer just above yours says the same.